# how to show view when keyboard appears in landscape

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, appdelegate, uikeyboard

I have a viewcontroller which has a username text field,pwd text field and a login button.

When i am in portrait mode i am not making any changes to the frame of viewcontroller's view,but when the orientation is changed to landscape i change the frame to push upwards.
The code works correctly but when i tap on the keyboard in portrait mode then press the home button
change the orientation to landscape 
open the app again
the view has not shifted on top,the keyboard appears to block the password field.

My question is how am i supposed to handle the view when app has transition from background to foreground after an orientation change?

I am using notifications for showing and hiding keyboard.

```
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
           name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
           name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

**show method:**

```
if(orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
self.view.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,-220,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);

}
```

hide method i am just changin y->0